# What is the equivalent ruby code for urllib2 in Python

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to pass url, headers and query_params. The following is the python code. I want to do it with ruby. I surfed the net and know Net::HTTP is the correct way of doing this. But this method does not accept query params and throws the error. What is the equivalent of the ruby code for the folowing python code?

Added file download link for both

[python](http://wikisend.com/download/121538/coinse.py)

[ruby](http://wikisend.com/download/395458/coinse.rb)

I want to have the same result in ruby also as in python.

```
nonce=1404996712857&method=neworder&rate=1&order_type=buy&quantity=1  //post_data(query params)

headers = {'key': '1234567894444444', 'sign': 'jhjhgyyqw7y890190800iihuhugdhugabnmKOP'}
```

Python

```
url_request_object = urllib2.Request("%s/%s" % (BASE_API_URL,url_suffix),
                                         post_data,
                                         headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(url_request_object)
```

Ruby

```
response = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, :body => post_data,:header => headers )
puts response.body
```

Error:

```
{"status": false, "message": "method required", "systime": 1404996498.0}
```

Comment: can you paste the full error?

Answer (score 0):

This should help you out.

```
require 'net/http'

html_request = Net::HTTP.new('site.com', 80)
path = '/path/where/form/is'
headers = {'Host' => 'site.com', 'Connection' => 'keep-alive', 'Key' => '1234567894444444', 'sign' => 'jhjhgyyqw7y890190800iihuhugdhugabnmKOP'}
post_data = 'nonce=1404996712857&method=neworder&rate=1&order_type=buy&quantity=1'

response = html_request.post(path, post_data, headers)
response_string = response.body.to_s
```